# How to deviate a list to container in YANG?

Tags: yang

I am trying to deviate a list to container in yang.
I tried going through RFC#6020, and I couldn't figure-out how to deviate on the container level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the type of a yang node.
However, you can use `deviate not-supported` on the *list* and `deviate add` on the parent node to create a new *container* with the same name as the *list*. The child elements of the *list* will be lost.

What you try to achieve is not a common use case and deviation modules are not designed to do what you request. A deviation should be used as a last resort to let netconf clients know that some part of the yang modules is not supported or only with restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. But you can use deviate not-supported on the list and augment a new container to the parent node. 'deviate' statment only can modify the poperties of data node ,but it can not add a new data node.